# how would i have more than one separate NetworkStream on the same port?

Tags: c#, tcp, port, networkstream

im making a Server-Client application..

chat

sends commands

file-transfer

i was wondering if it is possible to use only one port for all of them rather than (bind,listen,accept) for each port of them .. because in my application .. i want to connect once only .. and it seems ridiculous to connect 3 times .. how do i have a more than on separate NetworkStream if i want to connect (chat,commands,file-transfer) on the same port .. and if it's not possible.. what's the best structure to do that
im using tcp protocol for all of them.. hope i cleared my question .. thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can pass anything you want on that port. You can encapsulate your messages with a common header which would tell you whether the data to follow is a message, a command, or a file transfer. Breaking the messages into separate streams will just make it easier to decode what messages are what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, you don't need to have seperate NetworkDtream but you need to distinguish different resource type, which means, you just send that 3 types of resources in ONE NetworkStream and you can define some flags to distinguish them and them make different proceed.

Even though, I think you should have a extra port to transfer files , commands and chats were short while files data was quite big

Comment: yea .. and that what im doing .. but i still need to Connect two times.. one for the file transfer and one for chat/command .. when i connect to the port(chat/command) .. i send command to fire another connect for file transfer and it worked .. i just wondering if there's a simple way rather than doing this ..